# downloaded safari extension template in xcode, already getting 25 errors

Tags: xcode, safari-extension

I've downloaded Catalina, upgraded Xcode to 11.6, and decided to jump into my first Safari Extension project.  I downloaded the template and hit the run button.  I'm already getting 25 errors on it and I have no idea why.  Disclaimer: I'm new to coding.  So although I've been googling all day, I can't seem to find any help online.  [screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ynwD.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, not many people will be able to help with this question because we do not know what template you downloaded, what else you have tried, etc. Instead, I recommend you ask specific questions about specific error messages, include the entire error message in the question, and provide some background context (what template you are using, how to access it, etc)

Comment: The template is the safari extension template.  Most of the errors I'm getting are module errors.  There is a screenshot of the errors in the original post.  Also, thank you for the warm welcome!